# Today we've got (the regista)

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across this expression from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6ICPRWUqyg). I'm wondering what could *have got* mean in this context. I've looked up some dictionaries and nothing matches it. I assume he was saying "today we have got the regista to explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"have got" = "have".

"Regista" = central defender in American football.

The context is "We're going to continue on looking in depth into some  obscure player roles and today we've got the regista..."

Yes, you can use "have" or "have got" to talk about a subject for a lesson.  You can say

> In maths class today we've got quadratic equations.

"Have" is a very common word, with use that goes well beyond simple possession. Consider "have got a brother", "have a bath", "have got the flu".

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about relationships, possession, illness and characteristics of people and things, you can use either **have** or **have got**. They mean the same thing, although **have got** is less formal. For example:

> I have a cold.
>
> I have got a cold

> I have a boyfriend.
>
> I have got a boyfriend.

Keep in mind that there are exceptions where **have got** doesn't work. For example:

> I have a cold.  [ok]
>
> I have got a cold.  [ok]
>
> <strike>I have got a cold often</strike>.  [not ok]

So it's probably safest to just use **have**.

[Source: Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-and-have)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really don't understand what have got or have means here. The guy literally says "Today we (have got / have) the regista." The regista is a subject to talk about, not a thing to possess by anyone.